# Python pip install PythonMagick (Pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, pythonmagick

I'm trying to install package "PythonMagick" in pycharm but I've been getting this error

EDIT: I'm trying to run doc2text but I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PythonMagick'"

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PythonMagick (from versions: none)

> DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is
> deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A
> possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable,
> possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding
> this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333. ERROR: Could not find
> a version that satisfies the requirement PythonMagick (from versions:
> none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for PythonMagick

Has anyone had this before and can help me solve it :) ?

Thank you I appreciate any help

Comment: What your operating platform is?

Comment: Which version of python are you using

Comment: Windows 10, python 3.8 :)